# Using slicer instead of bookmark to display separate table visuals

Tags: dax

I have created 2 tables (sale by country and by product). Instead of using bookmark, how can I display them separately using a slicer? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2cnJ.png)
[image],
[image]

Appreciate your help very much

Comment: Check this article:
https://blog.octanesolutions.com.au/drill-down-using-slicer-in-power-bi

Comment: This is very helpful. I have my issue resolved. Many thanks.